# Write function to load set of predefined paths or files

Tags: r

I have recently made my first R package with specific tools for processing a large set of data that I am working with. In this project, there are several paths and files that I have to call and access at various points.

Is it possible to write functions that, when called will load a set of predefined paths or data to my global environment?

For example, the function

```
load_foo_paths()
```

would return

```
foo_path_1 <- "path/to/foo/1/"
foo_path_2 <- "path/to/foo/2/"
```

And the function

```
load_foo_data()
```

would return

```
foo_data_1 <- read.csv("foo_data_1.csv")
foo_data_2 <- read.csv("foo_data_2.csv")
```

How would I go about doing something like this?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO. Make sure to show what you have already tried. SO does not provide a code writing services, but we're happy to help with errors and trouble with what you have. Also, make sure you only have *one* question, and post another if you have more.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can adapt the following to your use case:

```
loadHist <- function() {

        HistFile        <- c(".Rhistory", ".Rsession")
        ruser           <- Sys.getenv("R_USER")                 # C:\cygwin64\home\xxxx
        whome           <- Sys.getenv("HOME")                   # C:\cygwin64\home\xxxx
        uprofile        <- Sys.getenv("USERPROFILE")    # C:\Users\xxxx

        # Setting up History Paths (to .Rhistory)
        hP1 <- c(getwd(), ruser, whome, uprofile)
        hP2 <- c(file.path(hP1, HistFile[1]))
        fe  <- file.exists(hP2)                                         # file.exists(file.path(getwd(), HistFile[1]))

        # Load first find
        fen = length(fe); i=1
        while (i <= fen) {
                if(fe[i]) {
                        cat('\nLoaded history from:\n',hP2[i],'\n', sep='')
                        try(utils::loadhistory(file=hP2[i]))
                        break
                }
                i = i + 1
        }
        #cat('\nDone!\n')
}
```